# Why does the WordPress bloginfo filter not filter anything?

Tags: php, wordpress

I use this code in my WordPress plugin:

```php
add_filter('bloginfo', function($output, $show) { return 'test'; }, 10, 2);
echo get_bloginfo('name'); // Prints out my site name
```

Obviously, this should always echo "test". However, the filter does not appear to work and I get the original site name without the filter applied.

Why does that happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the filter does not work on the call to `get_bloginfo` is that it only works if you request the bloginfo in "display" mode, i.e. with the seconds parameter set to "display":

```php
echo get_bloginfo('name', 'display'); // Prints out 'test'
```

With the 'display' filter, the bloginfo is returned HTML-escaped. You can read more about the `get_bloginfo` function in [the WordPress documentation for get_bloginfo](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/).

Unfortunately, you cannot filter the 'raw' value of `get_bloginfo` (which is the default). You can see this in the source code on https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/ (`if ( 'display' === $filter )`).